npm chain of linked dependencies
I have this chain of dependencies:
c->b->a

i tried to create e bash script to link them all.
cd a && npm link
cd b && npm link && npm link <absolute path to a>
cd c && npm link && npm link <absolute path to b>

when the script execute last step remove the symlink from node_modules b.
I don't understand why.
Someone can help me?

Why absolute paths instead of the actual package names?
